# opencv_highgui230.dll was not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, opencv

I am creating an application by using opencv2.3 IN VC++2010 express addition. The build is successful but while compiling it says that 'opencv_highgui230.dll was not found.Reinstalling the application may fix the problem.' Though I have added all the necessary include and lib files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that this DLL can be found in `bin` or similarly named directory under where you installed the OpenCV library. For Windows binary distributions of various libraries, the DLL is usually included.

For your program to load it, it either has to be in the same directory as the executable, in your system directory, usually `C:\Windows\system32\`, or I think that it is possible to specify the location programmatically, in your code. This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can tell you more.

Quick and, more likely then not, correct solution would be to copy the DLL into your executable's directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys,
Actually this DLL is located in the bin folder of opencv2.3 and I have added only the lib folder in additional dependencies.I don't know where to specify the path of this bin folder.

Comment: You don't. Just copy the DLL over to where your executable lives. If that is the `Debug` or `Release` subdirectory of your project directory, then it goes there.

Answer (score 0):

Because your application relies upon the library, you have to build the library *first* before you build your application. The error message is telling you that it can't find the binary file corresponding to your library, `opencv_highgui230.dll`, not one of the code files.

You can either configure Visual Studio to automatically build the projects in the correct order by setting up the appropriate project dependencies, or you can do it manually.